# second occurence of substring

Tags: python, string, indexing

Please write a program which finds the second occurrence of a substring. If there is no second (or first) occurrence, the program should print out a message accordingly.

```
n=input("please type the word: ")
c=input("Please type in a substring: ")
index=n.find(c)
index2=n.find(c,index+1)
if index2==-1:
    print("The substring does not occur twice in the string.")
else:
    print(f"The second occurrence of the substring is at index {index2}.")
```

for the input:abababa and aba
it should return index4 but it returns index 2
how to modify my code

Comment: You're mistaken: your substring is 1st found at index 0 then at index 2, so the result is correct. As far as I can see, your code is correct. Keep in mind that you can check the behaviour of your code by printing intermediate results (index for example) or running it in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see if you write it on paper and underline the sub-strings:

```
abababa
---
  ---
    ---
```

The substring is found three times, at index `0`, index `2` and index `4`.

If you want to skip overlapping sub-strings, you need to start the next search at index `len(c)`:

```
index2 = n.find(c, index + len(c))
```